# Bifurcation in 1D with two parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, bifurcation

I'm trying to do bifurcation analysis of the system

$x'=-x((x-2)^{2} - \mu^{2} -9)((x+2)^2 - \mu^2 -9)+ \epsilon$

When $\epsilon = 0$ this is easy because we have some nice circles. But I'm stuck as to what to do when $\epsilon > 0 $. I've been advised not to find analytic expressions for equilibria. I'm not looking for an explicit solution spelled out for me, just a shove in the right direction to be able to get there myself. How can one determine location/type of bifurcation for a system like this without known equilibria? Can I use my $\epsilon = 0$ diagram and infer something from it for $\epsilon >0$? What are my options here, methodology-wise?

Comment: It is easy to find the equilibria for $\epsilon=0$, as you mention yourself. Then you just need to translate the graph of the right-hand side by $\epsilon$ and you can proceed from there. PS: I wonder if you want $x''$ instead of $x'$.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It is only one derivative, although it should really be a dot since it's w.r.t. time.